# Векторное умножение векторов. Python, Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vector, вектор

Мне нужно узнать перпендикуляр к плоскости образованной двумя векторами в пространстве.
Я нашел в интернете, что это можно вычислить через [векторное умножение трехмерных векторов](https://ps-group.github.io/opengl/chapter_2_faq#wow1).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В коде это у меня выглядит вот так:

```py
def get_normal(translated_vec):
    line1 = translated_vec[1] - translated_vec[0]
    line2 = translated_vec[2] - translated_vec[0]

    normal = np.array([line1[1] * line2[2] - line1[2] * line2[1],
                       line1[2] * line2[0] - line1[0] * line2[2],
                       line1[0] * line2[1] - line1[1] * line2[0]])

    l = np.linalg.norm(normal)
    if l != 0:
        normal /= l
    else:
        normal += 1.0

    return normal
```

Пример входных данных:

```py
translated_vec = np.array([[ 0.07243389, -0.462265,    4.87585974],
                           [ 0.13487457, -0.3653465,   5.06419032],
                           [ 0.20468741, -0.1275775,   4.95642205]])
```

Это конечно работает, но работает слишком медленно, я хотел бы как-то это ускорить с помощью `numpy`, узнал что там есть функция `vdot`, но она мне не подходит, так как получая на вход два вектора, она выводит не новый вектор, а число. Т. е. мне нужно сделать быструю функцию которая вычисляет [это](https://ps-group.github.io/opengl/chapter_2_faq#wow1).

Comment: А просто `line1 * line2` не пробовали, не то получается, что нужно?

Comment: @CrazyElf нет, не то)

Comment: А `np.matmul` тоже не то? )

Comment: @CrazyElf мне нужно не число, мне нужен вектор в пространстве, поэтому, нет, тоже не подходит

Comment: Ну странно, `This is a scalar only when both x1, x2 are 1-d vectors.`, у вас что таки в `line1` и `line2`?

Comment: @CrazyElf ну, это одномерные массивы ```numpy```,  в которых хранятся три числа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [np.cross(a, b, axisa=- 1, axisb=- 1, axisc=- 1, axis=None)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html):

> Return the cross product of two (arrays of) vectors.
>
> **The cross product of `a` and `b` in  is a vector perpendicular to both `a`
> and `b`.** If `a` and `b` are arrays of vectors, the vectors are defined by
> the last axis of `a` and `b` by default, and these axes can have
> dimensions 2 or 3. Where the dimension of either `a` or `b` is 2, the
> third component of the input vector is assumed to be zero and the
> cross product calculated accordingly. In cases where both input
> vectors have dimension 2, the `z`-component of the cross product is
> returned.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Теперь я знаю про ```numpy``` немного больше)

Comment: @zolars `Numpy` похоже не исчерпаем, как атом. Но MaxU тоже не лыком шит, мы все у него учимся ))

Comment: Только есть одно но, это работает медленнее того что я привел(

Comment: @zolars, можете привести в вопросе воспроизводимые примеры данных?

Comment: @MaxU Да я привел правку в вопрос

Comment: @zolars, вы эту операцию в цикле будете выполнять? Если разово и для векторов одинаковой размерности, то вполне возможно, что тривиальная реализация будет быстрее, т.к. в ней не будет проверок и вызовов дополнительных встроенных функций

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо! Мы тут все друг у друга учимся)

Comment: @zolars Тогда можно вернуть старый вариант и попробовать обернуть его в `numba.njit`, но там придётся повозиться с типами, возможно.

Comment: @MaxU я понял, что если буду делать это в цикле, то это будет медленнее, поэтому теперь пытаюсь с помощью вашего решения сделать это без цикла, но застрял на этом фрагменте: ```l = np.linalg.norm(normal)
    if l != 0:
        normal /= l
    else:
        normal += 1.0 ```

Comment: @zolars, возможно стоит открыть новый вопрос с таким примером данных, который помог бы воспроизвести вариант с циклом и пояснить в этом вопросе более широко что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: я вот как раз и думал о том, стоит ли это делать)

Comment: @MaxU https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1377418/Нормализация-векторов-в-массиве-numpy