# Нормализация векторов в массиве numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vector, нормализация-данных

У меня есть массив `numpy` с полигонами и мне нужно получить массив с нормалями для этих полигонов, я нашел способ сделать это в цикле, но я хочу сделать это без цикла, ради большей скорости, но застрял на моменте с нормализацией нормалей.
Вариант с циклом:

```py
def get_normal(translated_vec):
    print(translated_vec)
    line1 = translated_vec[1] - translated_vec[0]
    line2 = translated_vec[2] - translated_vec[0]

    normal = np.array([line1[1] * line2[2] - line1[2] * line2[1],
                       line1[2] * line2[0] - line1[0] * line2[2],
                       line1[0] * line2[1] - line1[1] * line2[0]])

    l = sqrt(sum(np.power(normal, 2)))
    if l != 0:
        normal /= l
    else:
        normal += 1.73205080757

    return normal


translated_vec = np.array([[[ 0.07243389, -0.462265,    4.87585974],
                           [ 0.13487457, -0.3653465,   5.06419032],
                           [ 0.20468741, -0.1275775,   4.95642205]],
                          [[-0.0753569,  -0.142866,    4.75400399],
                           [ 0.12289676, -0.1275775,   4.83061181],
                           [ 0.02365434,  0.2133755,   4.71171791]]])

while True:
    for i, translated_vec in enumerate(translated_vecs):
         normal = get_normal(translated_vec)
```

Вариант без цикла:

```py
def get_normals(translated_vec):
    line1 = translated_vec[:, 1] - translated_vec[:, 0]
    line2 = translated_vec[:, 2] - translated_vec[:, 0]

    normal = np.cross(line1, line2)

    # Здесь фрагмент на котором я застрял

    sqrts = np.array([np.linalg.norm(n) for n in normal])

    # l = np.linalg.norm(normal)
    normal /= sqrts[:,np.newaxis]
    # if l != 0:
    #     normal /= l
    # else:
    #     normal += 1.73205080757

    return normal


translated_vec = np.array([[[ 0.07243389, -0.462265,    4.87585974],
                           [ 0.13487457, -0.3653465,   5.06419032],
                           [ 0.20468741, -0.1275775,   4.95642205]],
                          [[-0.0753569,  -0.142866,    4.75400399],
                           [ 0.12289676, -0.1275775,   4.83061181],
                           [ 0.02365434,  0.2133755,   4.71171791]]])

while True:
     normal = get_normals(translated_vec)
```

На выходе должно получиться это:

```py
[-0.93211486  0.33550072  0.13638602] # Нормаль первого полигона

[-0.36645627  0.20945855  0.90655222] # Нормаль второго полигона
```

Главная проблема в том, что я не знаю как быстро создать массив с длинами нормалей, чтобы потом разделить массив с нормалями на их длины и при этом, чтобы это было без цикла и быстро.

Comment: @MaxU да, я про него

Comment: @MaxU да, мой косяк, в np.array отправляю два массива как два аргумента, вместо одного массива как один аргумент

Comment: приведите пожалуйста в вопросе ожидаемый результат

Comment: @MaxU да, добавил, извините, что так поздно, просто когда вы попросили привести пример результатов  у меня было уже 3 часа ночи.

Comment: @MaxU я понял как исправить мою функцию и использовать ваш ответ на предыдущий вопрос, теперь я хотел у вас попросить проверить, правильно ли я все понял в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1377650/473641), спасибо вам что помогли мне и уделили мне время

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно немного оптимизировать ваше решение:

```
def get_normals(translated_vec):
    line1 = translated_vec[:, 1] - translated_vec[:, 0]
    line2 = translated_vec[:, 2] - translated_vec[:, 0]

    normal = np.cross(line1, line2)
    # NOTE: ---------------------------->  vvvvvv
    return normal / np.linalg.norm(normal, axis=1).reshape(len(normal), -1)
```

проверка:

```
In [37]: get_normals(translated_vec)
Out[37]:
array([[-0.93211486,  0.33550072,  0.13638602],
       [-0.36645627,  0.20945855,  0.90655222]])
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за вашу помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Я понял что у меня не так (или так), все что надо было, это ускорить вот эту конструкцию:

```py
sqrts = np.array([np.linalg.norm(n) for n in normal])
```

И вот как я это сделал:

```py
def get_normals(translated_vec):
    line1 = translated_vec[:, 1] - translated_vec[:, 0]
    line2 = translated_vec[:, 2] - translated_vec[:, 0]

    normal = np.cross(line1, line2)

    sqrts = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(normal, 2), axis=1))

    normal /= sqrts[:,np.newaxis]

    return normal
```

Я узнал подробнее про функцию `numpy.sum`, и понял как мне ускорить эту функцию без ошибок и с ожидаемым результатом.